# Dapper Distinguishing Return Value and Result Set

Tags: dapper

I am using `Dapper`'s `QueryMultipleAsync` method to read multiple result set. My stored procedure checks some conditions (for example a user might be trying to get someone else's data by sending an Id to my API) to determine whether the data should return or not.

I, on C# side, first need to read the `return value` (not result set) to determine if data is returned or SP simply returned 3 (which means insufficient rights). To illustrate the case:

```
IF @UserRole < 10
BEGIN
    RETURN 3; -- Insufficient rights.
END

IF @IsCurrentUserOwner = 0
BEGIN
    RETURN 5; -- Not owner.
END

-- Get users.
SELECT
        Id
    ,   [Name]
    ,   LastName
FROM
    Users
-- WHERE  ...

-- Get chat messages.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ChatMessages
-- WHERE  ...
```

I know that `output` and `return` values are written at the end of reader so I can only read return parameter when all the data (result set) is read. So, I always have to read the result set first then return/output parameters.

What if my `SP` looked like this:

```
-- ...some code above...
IF @IsCurrentUserOwner = 0
BEGIN
    RETURN 5; -- Not owner.
END

DECLARE @RType TINYINT = NULL

-- some other code here to get @RType value here...

SELECT @RType -- To make this a result so QueryMultiple's reader can read this.

-- ...some other code to get users and chat messages...
```

To describe the problem:

`@RType` variable could be `5` as well as `SP`'s return value. When I read the result first (because output/return parameters are at the end of reader), how do I know the value I just read (which is `5` in this case) is the @RType or return value? (they are convertible)

This is how my C# code roughly looks like:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@RetVal", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
var dbResult = await Context.SqlConnection.QueryMultipleAsync(sql: "my_sp_name", param: parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
// Some code here...

using (var reader = dbResult)
{
    var rType = reader.Read<byte>(); // <----- How to know if I read @RType or just return value of SP since they are convertible to each other?
    var users = reader.Read<User>();
    var chatMessages = reader.Read<ChatMessage>();
    // ...
}

var returnValue = parameters.Get<int>("@RetVal");
if (returnValue == 5)
{
    return "You are not allowed to see this data";
}
```

How do you recommend me to handle the case?

Comment: And this is why stored procs are the devil.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code uses async - await (QueryMultipleAsync) and currently Dapper doesn't support for Async methods that no perform a SELECT statement.
There is an open issue about that in Github:
https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/591

**Option 1**
You can split your stored procedure into 2 parts:
1. Check the Return value.
2. Getting the select statements.

**Option 2**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp
    ... your params..
    @Output INT OUTPUT
AS
    IF @UserRole < 10
    BEGIN
        SET @Output = 3; -- Insufficient rights.
    END

    IF @IsCurrentUserOwner = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Output = 5; -- Not owner.
    END

    -- Get users.
    SELECT
            Id
        ,   [Name]
        ,   LastName
    FROM
        Users
    -- WHERE  ...

    -- Get chat messages.
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ChatMessages
    -- WHERE  ...
```

**Option 3**
Use ADO.NET

Comment: I don't think what you posted here is related to my problem as I get the exact same result with QueryMultiple (not async) method.

Comment: You use QueryMultipleAsync

Comment: I also tried using QueryMultiple. I get the exact same result.

Comment: please try option 2

Comment: Output and return parameters are at the end of stream. I am not sure if you understood my problem.

Comment: @JustWork - I understood your problem, but not sure you understood your options.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't really clear on your question, but the snippet below should work. Since you are defining the @RetVal as ParameterDirection.ReturnValue you should be able to access it before accessing the actual readers. I was able to verify this works in SQL SERVER.

```
var returnValue = parameters.Get<int>("@RetVal");
if (returnValue == 5 || returnValue == 3)
{
    return "You are not allowed to see this data";
}


using (var reader = dbResult)
{
    var rType = reader.Read<byte>(); // <----- How to know if I read @RType or just return value of SP since they are convertible to each other?
    var users = reader.Read<User>();
    var chatMessages = reader.Read<ChatMessage>();
    // ...
}
```

here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE mysp_TestOne 
@p1 int 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    if @p1 > 0
    return 5;


    SELECT 1 F1
    union 
    Select 2 F1;

    SELECT 1 F1
    union 
    Select 2 F1;

END
GO
```

and more complete snippet of c#;

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

{
    var sql = @"mysp_TestOne";
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

    // @p1 triggers whether to return query results or just the returnvalue
    parameters.Add("p1", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);
    parameters.Add("@RetVal", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
    var dbResult = await cn.QueryMultipleAsync(sql, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    var returnValue = parameters.Get<int>("@RetVal");
    if (returnValue == 5 || returnValue == 3)
    {
        return "You are not allowed to see this data";
    }


    using (var reader = dbResult)
    {
        var rType = reader.Read<byte>(); // <----- How to know if I read @RType or just return value of SP since they are convertible to each other?
        var users = reader.Read<User>();
        var chatMessages = reader.Read<ChatMessage>();
        // ...
    }

}
```

HTH

Comment: How this solves my problem? Where do you read return value?  How do you know "var rType = reader.Read<byte>();" reads result not return value?

Comment: @JustWork, i amended my answer. You had it correct just needed to move retrieving your return value to before accessing your readers.

Comment: That doesn't work, should not work as I have seen that return/output parameters should be read after the result set.

Comment: It is working for me. I am using sql 2017 with latest dapper from nuget. I will amend the answer with my sproc listing and a more complete snippet.

Comment: @JustWork, I changed the place in the sproc that the return occurs. I move it to the bottom, and now my returnValue doesn't contain a value. I guess If you keep the checks and return immediately at the very beginning of the sproc it should work for you.